# website UI & functionality issues with Internet explorer 10

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, firefox, user-interface, internet-explorer-10

I have an ASP.net website that was working fine with IE9, Mozilla, chrome but with IE users have lot issues. The UI and even the functionality (like clicking on button, login/logout do not work).

The IE version I have is 10.0.9200.16519.

Here are some of the things I did so far,

a) I have compared the view-source of both IE 10 and chorome and see some differences. I am going through them.

b) I am trying to trace through fiddler tool on the IE 10 site.

Please suggest what are the best options to check for browser issues. The site works fine with IE9 and below versions of IE.

Thanks,

PS: I am trying to make the site public facing and will post the url if someone can provide their inputs.

Comment: What are the *specific* issues you're having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an old bug in asp.net which is well explained here: [Browser definition bug in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

..basically it results in javascript requests not being handled properly when they come from unrecognised browsers.  IE10 falls into this category.

Fortunately it's an old bug and it's been patched - with these hotfixes:

This one for .NET 2.0 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100

And this one for .NET 4.0 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

Which are probably also available through Windows Update by now as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the source is different, then your server is sending a different page to IE users. You are probably using IE conditional comments (e.g., `<!--[if IE]>`). IE10 does **not** support conditional comments, unlike IE9 or lower.

Comment: We have not any conditional statements. I still don' understand why view source is different.

Comment: Check your ASP. For some reason, your server is sending a different page to IE users.

Comment: Can you please let me know where to check in ASP? Our site is ASP.NET site and the only thing I found out so far is that ControlsAdapters.browser file under App_browsers has this value   <browser refID="IE6to9">. Do I need to make any change here?

Comment: Can anyone suggest where can I check how the server is sending pages to IE? Where are these settings for ASP.Net site?